# Garson 2.7 (Tense Logic)

Tags: modal-logic

Exercise 2.7 wants me to prove **PG**A -> A in Kt. Summarily speaking, **G/H** (in/out) is exactly like [  ]in and [  ]out. [pp.50-51 lays out the rules in detail]

Kt=PL + **G/H** (in/out) + **GP** +**HF**

**GP**= A -> **GP**A

**HF**=A -> **HF**A

Some identities:

**F**A=~**G**~A

**P**A=~**H**~A

***Edit:***

This is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to note that the theorems of propositional logic are unconditionally available for the system Kt and the expression sought after is only the contrapositive of the HF axiom modulo simple substitutions.

Comment: Yup, realized that.